# Restored SD card fails to boot with prompting "initramfs"

Tags: boot, backup, sd-card, dd

What I did:

0. format a blank SD card

```
    sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdf
```

1. create img file from the other SD card. The card has Ubuntu server 20.04 system.

```
    sudo dd if=/dev/sde of=~/backup.img bs=4096000
```

2. restore img into the formated SD card.

```
    sudo dd if=~/backup.img of=/dev/sdf bs=4096000
```

3. boot Raspberry Pi 4 with restored SD card. Then boot fails and,  "initramfs" shows up at the head of the command line.

How should I avoid this situation and, boot successfully with restored SD card?

[image of display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0Cxr.jpg)

Comment: I'd guess that `/etc/fstab`  specifies partitions by `UUID=`, The UUIDs of the new SD cards partitions are different (Universally Unique ID, after all). `sudo lsblk --fs` and edit `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Let me ask you where I should do the operation you suggested. 
How do I list devices without using `lsblk`? Because it is not available in my situation.
So I tried to add a line `/dev/sda1 /home ext4 defaults 1 1` In anticipation, but it failed.